# MySql query : Get sum of N rows where N is defined in another column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table,

```
 id  |   add_card_id |   rate | category |  category_count |    counts | total
7597 |    723        |    3   |   7      |      1          |     300   | 108
7596 |    723        |    3   |   9      |      1          |     500   | 180
7594 |    723        |    3   |   11     |      1          |     400   | 240
7593 |    723        |    5   |   10     |      2          |     400   | 240
7593 |    723        |    5   |   13     |      2          |     400   | 240
```

I want to get sum of `total`(column name) where `rate` is same but sum include only nth no. of rows having max total,  nth is defined by `category_count` (column name).

e.g the rate of first three column is  3 and category_ count is 1 so sum (total) first three rows is 240 because 240 > 180 > 108 and in the case of last two rows rate is 5 and category_count is 2 so 240 +240= 480 and i want 720= 240(from first three rows) + 480 (from last two rows).

I have tried the following query

```
SELECT SUM(total) 
FROM (SELECT MAX(total) 
      FROM tableName 
      GROUP BY rate, category_count) as newTable
```

it's giving me 240+ 240 so how can I give the limit by `category_count`(column)?

Comment: To confirm, for rate=3 you just want one row from rate=3 because category_count is one, and that it must choose the highest total (i.e. order by total desc?)

Comment: yes,  @StuartLC you are right.

Comment: See the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group) for getting the top `N` rows per group. You just have to change it so that `N` comes from the `category_count` column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION BY in MySql by dynamically assigning variables

```
SELECT rate, SUM(total) 
FROM 
(
  SELECT total, rate, category_count, 
         -- Row num counter, resets at each different rate
         @row_num := IF(@prev_rate=rate, @row_num+1, 1) AS RowNum, 
         @prev_rate := rate -- Track to see if we are in the same rate
  FROM tableName,
     (SELECT @row_num := 1) x, -- Set initial value for @row_num and @prev_rate
     (SELECT @prev_rate := '') y
  -- Important, must keep rates together, then order by your requirement
  ORDER BY rate ASC, total DESC 
) ranked
WHERE ranked.RowNum <= ranked.category_count -- Your requirement of TOP N
GROUP BY rate;
```

The above returns

```
Rate Total
3    240
5    480
```

And if you do the `SELECT SUM(total)` then drop the GROUP BY you'll get 720 as you want.

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6689/6)

**Edit**

It seems rate is defined as (I'd assumed an integer from your sample data)

```
`rate` varchar(X) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
```

Change the one line:

```
 (SELECT @prev_rate := '' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci) y
```

Which will set the temporary tracking variable to the same type as your column

Comment: It's giving the following err
Error Code: 1267
Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
select sum(cnt) from(select max(cnt)cnt from
(SELECT rate, category_count,total*count(*)cnt FROM tableName GROUP BY rate, category_count,total)temp group by rate, category_count)temp
```

[Here My Example see the link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28fe9/5/0)